# All Countries States Cities and Zipcodes in a Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation

Is there a way getting all countries, states,cities zipcodes/ in one single database.

I have been looking all over.

I discovered [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org), which has I guess all of the content. But there is no way to fetch that data directly.

I am using rails. If there any helpers or Plugins, it'd be great. It would be awesome if there is a complete resource in any parsable format which I can use to get this database in place.

Please recommend if you any thanks

I do have the iso country code list but no States for some countries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But what about places that don't have states or zip codes?

Comment: Don't try to know the whole world! The user know best where he lives than you. Yesterday, Google Checkout refuses to accept my zip code, because it was incorrect (for them). I was forced to use an incorrect value to register!

Comment: Do you passed by a database or lookup service that provides the borders of a city, state or country in form of gps points (polylines)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks Guys,

I got all the the countries and states of all of them, but no zip codes.

> http://27.org/isocountrylist/iso_country_list.sql

This contains all countries, and there iso-3166 codes ( Siberia code needs to be changed from "CS" to "RS")

And here is the FIPS file for countries with states

> http://www.maxmind.com/app/fips_include

For zip code validation I am using

> http://www.geonames.org webservices

There is a geonames ruby gem as well, which makes it really simple to do zipcode validations

Hope that helps anybody who needs this information, worth keeping it handy for web projects.

Another Link ( thanks @laise ): http://dev.maxmind.com/static/csv/codes/maxmind/region.csv

Comment: Can second link be raplaced with [this one](http://dev.maxmind.com/static/csv/codes/maxmind/region.csv)?

Answer (score 4):

The [Carmen plugin](http://github.com/jim/carmen) is almost certainly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I checked it out as well. I found what i needed though. Worth checking it out ( details below ). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will take a little legwork and data munging, but it's not too bad.

Countries and country codes are easy to come by. Sounds like you already have them.

Not all countries are divided into states. You may have to simply address these one by one-- there may be some combined reference, but not that I know of.

U.S. cities are available, and look for things like [FIPS codes](http://mcdc.missouri.edu/webrepts/commoncodes/ccc_az.html#metro). There are commercial data providers that will provide you clean, well-organized data, but they are charging for it.

The post office has some databases with all the zip codes. Note that these charge periodically, and a single zip code doesn't imply a single single (far from it!). And it may not be necessary to actually have a database of all of them, as there are zip verification/correction services available for free.

For loading the data, check out [a recent railscast on the subject.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)

Comment: Thanks,I found what i needed. Worth checking it out ( details below )

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and found this resource. I hope somebody serves well as me.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/index.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

For those using the FIPS 10-4/FIPS 5-2 standard, I have been maintaining the NGA GEC (formerly FIPS 10-4/5-2) Excel spreadsheet (original format) for 1st level administrative divisions of countries. The spreadsheet is currently updated to Update 15 (March 2014):
http://www.opengeocode.org/archive.php